# Passing CGI parameters to a form via an URL

Tags: url, cgi

I am trying to pass arguments to this CGI form (http://www.westegg.com/inflation/) through the URL, so I don't have to manually type them in, and so that I can generate URLs through other means for faster use.

Here is the CGI form code from the site:

```
<form action="infl.cgi" method="post">

Enter the amount of money: <input name="money" type="text" size="9">

<p>

Enter the initial year (1800-2008): 
<input name="first" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4">

<p>

Enter the final year (1800-2008):
<input name="final" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="2007">

<p>
<center>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</center>
</form>
```

I've tried passing arguments via the "?" and "&" syntax, but none of these work:

```
http://www.westegg.com/inflation/infl.cgi?money=1&first=1800&last=1900
http://www.westegg.com/inflation/infl.cgi?money="1.00"&first="1800"&last="1900"
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you control `westegg.com`? Clearly, `infl.cgi` is written to process forms that are `POST`'ed. You can, of course, still automate your posts using commonly available tools, just not by typing the information in the address bar. And, I am not sure if this is not abusing the resources of the web site. Come to think of it, **do you have a programming question?** Didn't think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the form uses the `POST` method, not `GET`. It's impossible to just pass the arguments in the URL. There's a lot of information out there how `POST` works.

Comment: Ah, I thought POST might be a problem. Sorry, I am unfamiliar with CGI :( So it is simply impossible to pass arguments through the URL then? How does the POST method work differently from GET?

Comment: You should easily be able to find information regarding how the HTTP protocol (including how GET and POST differ) works through Google!

Comment: To use a GET all you need to do is pass options through the URL, to use a POST you need to pass the data through the HTTP header of the request. You would therefore need to build your own http requests in code or use a framework to do that for you.

Comment: ...for some value of "impossible". The back-end code can be written to recognize both URL and body parameters/arguments, but that generally takes a bit of extra effort as most interfaces to cgi will default to ignoring URL params if a request body is present. So don't expect arbitrary third-party sites to let you mix-and-match; they're probably not making the effort to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

SO I was able to get something similar to work.  First, make sure that you've got the right parameters and names (you've got the variable names apparently).  You'll need to look at the source code of the resultant page, but you need to find the variable that executes the form.  In my case I was using a search page and the button name was "searchresultFlag".  Try something like:

http://www.westegg.com/inflation/infl.cgi?money=1&first=1800&final=1900&searchresultFlag=1

My parameters were different from yours, but this worked for me.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: This method worked for me, on a CGI form that used POST. Thank you.